# remove class with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to remove the hidden class if the screen size reaches a certain size with coffeescript. Here is my current code:

### coffeescript:

```
$(window).resize "form.edit_customization", (event) =>
  if $(window).width() <= 768
    removeClass '.hidden'
```

### HTML:

```
<p class="hidden">Please use desktop or larger display when editing an event</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need JS to do that, CSS would be enough, something like this should work:

HTML:

```
<p class="small-screen-message">Please use desktop or larger display when editing an event</p>
```

CSS:

```
.small-screen-message {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .small-screen-message {
    display: inline;
   }
}
```

Here is an example [JS bin](https://jsbin.com/pawijocexo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the `removeClass` function from which element the class should be removed. So if you want to remove the hidden-class from all elements that currently have that class you can write

```
$(".hidden").removeClass "hidden"
```

However, you won't be able to select all those elements again if the screensize goes back to above 768px. To be able to do that you can add a `can-be-hidden` class to those elements. So your HTML would be

```
<p class="hidden can-be-hidden">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

and the JS

```
if $(window).width() <= 768
  $(".can-be-hidden").removeClass 'hidden'
else
  $(".can-be-hidden").addClass 'hidden'
```

P.S. `removeClass '.hidden'` will look for elements like `<p class=".hidden">`, not `<p class="hidden">` so better don't use a dot here